# Best way to save an empty date into a date field in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the best and safer way in a MySQL database to set a date or datetime fiel to `''` during an `INSERT` or it it better to make `'0000-00-00'` or `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` ?

Example:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table (name, date) VALUES (:name, :date)');
$query->execute(array(':name' => 'Thomas', ':date' => ''));
```

Thanks.

Comment: `NULL` is used to indicate the absence of a value in a field with the correct type for the expected data.

Comment: i recommend to set it to NULL and not to '0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the attribute isn't set as `NOT NULL` and then in the SQL put something like `INSERT INTO cutomers (fname, lname, date_of_birth) VALUES ("Mike", "Smith", null);`